# R - positive definite matrix in bayesm packet

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, bayesian

I am new to R and I am entirely dependent on Google to help me sail. I am working on a Bayesian Hierarchical Linear Model. My case is very similar to the one on the link: http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/rbayes/rhierlmc

Categories are defined by Catcode. I am trying to estimate beta coefficients of various regressors in the model. Code is working fine and I am getting beta values as well for all regressors except one - Overall. The moment I add this variable into the model, I get the error:

```
Error in chol.default(XpX/sigmasq + A) : 
 the leading minor of order 7 is not positive definite
```

The order number (7 here) can be anything between 1 to 7 depending upon the position of Overall in the model

Full Code:

```
library(bayesm) 
str(Hier_Rank)

codeFactors <- factor(Hier_Rank$Catcode)
codeLevels <- levels(codeFactors)
lengthofCodeLevels <- length(codeLevels);
lengthofCodeLevels
regdata <-NULL
for (i in 1:lengthofCodeLevels) { 

 filter = Hier_Rank$Catcode == codeLevels[i] 

 y = Hier_Rank$Sales[filter] 
 X = cbind(1, Hier_Rank$Price[filter], Hier_Rank$Adspends[filter]      ,Hier_Rank$US.small.min[filter], Hier_Rank$US.mid.min[filter],  Hier_Rank$US.large.min[filter], Hier_Rank$Overall[filter])

    regdata[[i]] = list(y=y, X=X) 
 }


Data <− list(regdata=regdata) 
Mcmc <− list(R=2000) 

system.time(
output<-bayesm::rhierLinearModel(
Data=Data,
Mcmc=Mcmc))  

beta.2 <− mean(as.vector(output$betadraw[, 2, 201:2000]))
beta.2
beta.3 <− mean(as.vector(output$betadraw[, 3, 201:2000])) 
beta.3
beta.4 <− mean(as.vector(output$betadraw[, 4, 201:2000]))
beta.4
beta.5 <− mean(as.vector(output$betadraw[, 5, 201:2000]))
beta.5
beta.6 <− mean(as.vector(output$betadraw[, 6, 201:2000]))
beta.6
beta.7 <− mean(as.vector(output$betadraw[, 7, 201:2000]))
beta.7
```

I am getting all beta values except for beta 7 for which I get the error:

```
Error in output$betadraw[, 7, 201:2000] : subscript out of bounds
```

Data looks like:

```
Sales Price Adspends   US.small.min    US.mid.min   US.large.min  Overall CatCode
 10     0.5   123          1               0             0          5       1
 20     0.7   133          0               4             0          4       2
 24     0.8   400          0               0             6          3.5     3
 30     0.66  155          3               0             0          6       1
 34     0.4   166          0               8             0          7       2
 35     0.3   229          6               0             0          4.5     1
```

Can someone please help?

I have additional questions for this code. 
1) How can I modify same code for panel data
2) How do I find standard errors for the beta coefficients?

Comment: If you are confused about the words `except` and `expect` as I suspect, then you should change the two erroneous "expect"'s to `except`'s

Comment: Thank you BondedDust. I edited the word.